# How can set different arrays that deals with different range of values?

Tags: php

I want to achieve the following html dynamically:

**Time period AD:**

```
<ul>
  <li>1200</li>
  <li>1300
    <ul>
      <li>1301</li>
    </ul>
  <li>
</ul>
```

**Time period BC:**

```
<ul>
  <li>-200</li>
  <li>-450
    <ul>
      <li>-451</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the following I have set an array so that I can, by using some custom fields, push my dates into the array, then tell the whole code to calculate in 100 of years, in order to be able to place years like `1301` as a nested ul under `1300`.

```
         <ul>
            <?php 
                $yearsArray = [];
                $centuryHash = [];
                query_posts(array( 
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1
                ));
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    array_push($yearsArray, get_field("year"));
                    if (($wp_query->current_post +1) == ($wp_query->post_count)) {
                        $yearsArray = array_unique($yearsArray);
                        sort($yearsArray);
                    }
                endwhile; 
                foreach ($yearsArray as $year) {

                    $currentCentury = floor($year/100)*100;

                    if(!$centuryHash[$currentCentury]){
                        $centuryHash[$currentCentury] = [];
                    }

                    if($currentCentury != $year){
                        $centuryHash[$currentCentury][] = $year;
                    }
                }
                foreach ($centuryHash as $century => $centuryYears) { ?>
                    <li class="dropdown"> 
                        <?php if($centuryYears){ ?>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-date="<?php echo $century; ?>" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <?php echo $century; ?>
                                <span class='caret'></span> 
                            </a>
                            <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                                <?php foreach ($centuryYears as $year) { ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <a class="btn btn-default" data-date="<?php echo $year; ?>" href="#">
                                            <?php echo $year; ?>
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                <?php }
                            echo "</ul>";
                        } else { ?>
                            <a class="btn btn-default" data-date="<?php echo $century; ?>" href="#">
                                <?php echo $century; ?>
                            </a>    
                        <?php } ?>
                    </li>
                <?php }
            ?>
        </ul>
```

The problem that I can't figure out is how I can say like (verbal code):

***If value is within the range of -450 till 2 then go into this array otherwise go in that array instead***

From my end I could set in the cms (people will be able to insert content with dates) some flags so that I can do simple conditionals like (verbal code):

***"Is this date from a or b? then do this or that"***

*But that creates an issue because I could flag a period of time and place the wrong date in the wrong period.*

Therefore the last solution that I thought is to set a range of periods of times and delimiter some arrays by create different ones where I could dynamically push the values depending on their values.

This could be a start maybe ([example from docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php))? But how can I set an `if` to control what goes there or not?

```
foreach (range(0, 12) as $number) {
    echo $number;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple answer to your question.

> **If value is within the range of -450 till 2 then go into this array otherwise go in that array instead**

```
if ($value >= -450 && $value <= 2) {
    // do this
} else {
    // do that
}
```

Hope, this answers to your question (which is, unfortunately, overloaded with dozens of code that doesn't apply to the question).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and it's actually quite simple, maybe i was just overloaded with the whole code above.